# Button ClickListener crashes app

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm trying to make an application that has multiple tabs, and for now I only have the tabs to worry about. The problem I have is that, when I uncomment the button setOnClickListener it gives me an error when trying to run it on the AVD.
Here is my main function
`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle Bgilca) {
    Button blade;
    super.onCreate(Bgilca);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    launchMusic = MediaPlayer.create(main.this, R.raw.powerup);
    launchMusic.start();
    Thread launchTime = new Thread(){             
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            launchMusic.pause();


        }
    }
    };launchTime.start();




}
Button blade = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fantab);


}`
```

when trying to execute in the AVD, the app crashes giving the message"unfortunately app_name has stopped"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bgilcag60"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation ="portrait"  

         >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ventscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.bgilag60.ventscreen" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

'

here is my Layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
tools:context="com.example.bgilcag60.main" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scaunstg"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/scaunstg"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
    android:clickable="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scaundr"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/scaundr"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
    android:clickable="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/corrado_home"
    android:clickable="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/head"
android:layout_width="66dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@drawable/head_tab"
android:clickable="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/navi"
android:layout_width="66dp"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginRight="95dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/head"
android:background="@drawable/navi_tab"
android:clickable="true" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/fantab"
android:layout_width="66dp"
android:layout_height="66dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginRight="95dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/navi"
android:background="@drawable/fan_tab"
android:clickable="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my logcat

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDUQC.png

any ideas?

Comment: this line Button blade = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fantab); should be in onCreate but it isn't.. It is outside the oncreate call inside the class..re-check..and re run. and let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that `findViewById` **outside** the `onCreate` method and it's *not located inside any method*.

---

Also you are defining `Button blade` **twice**.

So once you have defined button blade, then *while referencing to it, you should not define it again.*

So your your line should be -

```
blade = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fantab);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is about a null pointer on this line:

```
Button blade = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fantab);
```

Since you have the button in your xml, most likely you are not pointing to the right layout file:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

It means the layout file must be `main.xml` or you change the code to point to the right layout.

```
setContentView(R.layout.Layout);//from your post "here is my Layout.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cause by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app...FindviewbyID   
at android.app.....main<init>(main.java:48);
```

the problem is there are object that findviewbyID by wrong reference. check carefull in line 48.

Answer (score 0):

so apparently the problem was that the findViewById was after the bracket of the OnCreate function. Thank you for your answers.